# iOS UIView animation not working correctly

Tags: objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

I want to create recursive animation. Here my code:

```
- (void)startAnimation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                     animations:^{
                         NSLog(@"animation");
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if(!canceled) {
                             NSLog(@"completed");
                             [self startAnimation];
                         }
                     }
     ];
}
```

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     //somewhere in your app, possibly viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.
     [self startAnimation];
}
```

ISSUE:**animation** and **completed** were shown at the same time. Where my error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                 delay:3.0
                 animations:^{
                     NSLog(@"animation");
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if(!canceled) {
                         NSLog(@"completed");
                         [self startAnimation];
                     }
                 }
 ];
```

Comment: When you post a blob of code like this. Please explain the change and why it works. "Try this" is not a suitable answer

Comment: if you have a change, try using core animation